# Free motion blur removal from video?

Tags: gratis, open-source, video, images, image-processing

I need to be able to remove the motion blur from the individual frames of a video, so that each frame is sharp. Currently, some of the frames are sharp, and some are blurry, but I need them all to be sharp.

I'm also ok with software that can deblur an image, but if so I would need it to be able to process a batch of images, so that I can run it on all the frames, instead of doing it one by one.

It needs to be free or have a free edition that is at least ok to use for noncommercial purposes, and optimally open source

I prefer a linux program, but I'm also fine with a Windows one if that's all there is

Answer (score 1):

[SmartDeblur](http://smartdeblur.net/)'s PRO version has [command line interface](http://smartdeblur.net/tutorial.html#CommandLine) that let you process images in batch mode.

For more information, visit SmartDeblur's developer website: 
http://yuzhikov.com/index.html

Previous versions of SmartDeblur are available for free here: https://github.com/Y-Vladimir/SmartDeblur/downloads

You might also consider [VideoCleaner](http://videocleaner.com).